# Django choice field inside of the forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model

```
class Book(models.Model):
    JANUARY = '1'
    FEBRUARY = '2'
    MARCH = '3'
    APRIL = '4'
    MAY = '5'
    JUNE = '6'
    JULY = '7'
    AUGUST = '8'
    SEPTEMBER = '9'
    OCTOBER = '10'
    NOVEMBER = '11'
    DECEMBER = '12'

    MONTH_CHOICES = (
        (JANUARY, 'January'),
        (FEBRUARY, 'February'),
        (MARCH, 'March'),
        (APRIL, 'April'),
        (MAY, 'May'),
        (JUNE, 'June'),
        (JULY, 'July'),
        (AUGUST, 'August'),
        (SEPTEMBER, 'September'),
        (OCTOBER, 'October'),
        (NOVEMBER, 'November'),
        (DECEMBER, 'December'),
    )

    name = models.CharField('Book name', max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    author_email = models.EmailField('Author email', max_length=75, blank=True)
    imported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    published = models.DateField('Published', blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    month = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices= MONTH_CHOICES,
        default=JANUARY,
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am trying to create a field for a month inside of my queryset. How should i do that I tried Book.objects.all().values('month) but that would only give me the existing data not all the months

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your question title mentions forms.py, but the body of the question doesn't mention forms at all and instead talks about querysets. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: So basically I need to create a form that has month column as a choice field. I defined my fields fields = ('name', 'price','month') and I want to have a choice field for the all 12  month. I tried to approach this using queryset, but it only gives me records I enter input_months = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Months', queryset=Book.objects.all().values('month'))

Comment: You need to show the code for your form. Since MONTH_CHOICES is already set the as choices for the month field, you shouldn't need to do anything at all. You don't need a ModelChoiceField.

Comment: class CustomImportForm(ImportForm):
    #this is the custom field 
    input_months = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Months', queryset=Book.objects.all().values('month'))